# Magento 2.1.3 Custom Payment Method not showing while showing in Magento 2.1.1?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, payment-methods, magento-2.1.3

I have created 1 custom payment method in magento 2.1.1.

Its working fine in it.

Now I have upgraded to magento 2.1.3.

Now in Magento 2.1.3 custom method is not showing at admin and frontend.

What happend actually I'm not getting.

Can anyone help me...

Comment: Can you post your module on Github and give us the link here?

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh I can provide info here. What do u want to know?

Comment: I need to see your module and test it on my local machine.

Comment: Do you use `sortOrder` attribute in your `CustomPayment\etc\adminhtml\system.xml` file for payment group xml node? Can you post this xml file?

Comment: @jonijones <group id="payfull" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">

Comment: Try, to change `sortOrder` to `5` or bigger. Possible your trouble related to https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7891 issue.

Comment: @jonijones Ok Thanks I will tell tell u what happens after that.

Comment: @jonijones You are right that was sortorder problem. Thanks.